# Unable to parser MYSQL timestamp using SimpleDateFormat in Android

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I am using the following to parse a string to date. However I get an Unparseable date exception. This is the code

```
String dateString="2018-09-20T11:44:48.000Z";//MYSQL timestamp from server
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.S'Z'");
Date convertedDate = new Date();
try {
  convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString); //error here
  textTime.setReferenceTime(convertedDate.getTime());
} catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: (1) Don’t get a string from MySQL, get an `Instant`, `LocalDateTime` or `Timestamp`, whichever works. (2) Consider avoiding the `SimpleDateFormat` class, it’s long outdated and notoriously troublesome. If java.time, the modern Java date and time API, isn’t built into your Android version, consider [the ThreeTenABP library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), the backport of java.time for Android.

Comment: Also don’t parse the `Z` in the date string as a literal (in single quotes). It’s a UTC offset and needs to be parsed as such. Otherwise `SimpleDateFormat` will use the JVM’s time zone, leading to an incorrect point in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rectify your [**`SimpleDateFormat`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
   String dateString="2018-09-20T11:44:48.000Z";

   SimpleDateFormat inputFormat     = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S'Z'");
   SimpleDateFormat outputFormat    = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.S'Z'");

    Date   convertedDate    = null;
    String strOP            = null;

    try 
    {
        convertedDate = inputFormat.parse(dateString);
        strOP         = outputFormat.format(convertedDate);
        textTime.setReferenceTime(strOP);
    } 
    catch (ParseException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```